# is there anyway to copy podcasts from my computer to my blackberry torch

Tags: podcasts, blackberry

I use itunes with my ipod so i have lots of podcasts on my pc. Is there anyway to copy these over to my blackberry torch.

I see there is a podcast app for the torch but it wants me to enter the url of the podcast feed.

I dont want to download the podcasts wirelessly to my blackberry (to avoid charges) so I wanted to see if i could copy them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the old fashioned way. Connect your phone to your computer and it will appear in as a thumb drive. Copy the files over to the \BlackBerry\Music\ folder and play in the media app.

The Desktop Manager also has an application in it to help copy over media and other files as well which you can get on Rim's website for BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0):

You will also find that even if you dump the files into a specific folder on your Blackberry or its memory card, the files will themselves still be sorted differently in the Media player interface.  (Well at least in OS 5.  No idea if this is still true on OS 6, since the Torch has the newest OS).

You may also find it easier to pop out the memory card to connect to your computer, depending on what sort of cables and connectors you have handy.